# Display alert if clicking outside div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div class ".square", i want to show an alert if there is a mouse clicking outside of the div element, i can't find something similar according to mouse event on this website  [w3schools.](http://w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp) ( i want the opposite of my actual code ) Thank you.

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('hi')
}
```

```css
.square{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="square" onclick="myFunction()" ></div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Simple solution**: Add a listener to the window that produces the `alert` and add a listener to the div that [stops the click event from propagating](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) so that it never reaches the window.

Disclaimer: calling `stopPropagation` is not a great thing to do as it's quite intrusive, but I'm guessing you're just trying things out, so it should be fine.

```js
window.onclick = () => alert('hi')
```

```css
.square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div onclick="event.stopPropagation()" class="square">TEST</div>
```

[Here's a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3028037/3755425) that describes a more proper way to achieve this.

And here's that answer adjusted to your case in a more **correct solution** where we look at the click event to determine if we should call `alert`:

```js
const outsideClickListener = element => ({ target }) => {
  if (!element.contains(target)) {
    alert("hi");
  }
};

const squareEl = document.getElementById("square");
document.addEventListener("click", outsideClickListener(squareEl));
```

```css
#square{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  background-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<div id="square">TEST</div>
```

Why should we not use `stopPropagation`? In a small project there's not a big problem to use it (which is why it's my top recommendation). But in a big real world project it's ill advice, because it can break behavior of other stuff. See below example. Developer A added `Test 1` and expects `alert('hi 1')` to be ran every time the user clicks outside of `Test 1`. But developer B added `Test 2` which calls `stopPropagation` that stops all events, so when the user clicks `Test 2` (which is outside of `Test 1`) `alert('hi 1')` is not ran and we have a bug.

```js
window.onclick = () => alert('hi 2')

const outsideClickListener = element => ({ target }) => {
  if (!element.contains(target)) {
    alert("hi 1");
  }
};

const squareEl = document.getElementsByClassName("square")[0];
document.addEventListener("click", outsideClickListener(squareEl));
```

```css
.square, .circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  color: red;
  background-color: teal;
}

.square {
  background-color: teal;
}

.circle {
  background-color: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="square">TEST 1</div>
<div onclick="event.stopPropagation()" class="circle">TEST 2</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i didn't understund what you meant by "stopPropagation is not a great thing to do as it's quite intrusive" can you please explain ?

Comment: There you go, I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: Yes now i get it, it can create confusion between elements, i'm willing to use it as an exit on a popup if you click outside it, so i'll take your second answer, thank you very much sir, very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="square">squre</div>
.square{
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid red;
}



let sq = document.querySelector('.square');
window.addEventListener('click', function(e){  
    if (sq.contains(e.target)){
       alert('inside square box')
    } else{
       alert('outside square box')
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make a click event listener for the body.

If the body is clicked check if the target is the square, or if the target is a child of the square

```js
function myFunction() {
  alert('hi');
}
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  if($(e.target).is('.square') || $(e.target).closest('.square').length) {
    myFunction();

  }
});
});
```

```css
.square{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
color: red;
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div class="square">
</div>
<body>
```